# How can I run my queries and transactions within a block and then check the runtime and store the results in a separate table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a game idea, and have created some dummy data, with some queries and transactions. However, I am having a hard time including my queries and transactions into a block for measurements. I am using Oracle 18c express.
**My problem is that I can't find the correct syntax for running queries that select whole rows or even tables, or transactions within the block**
what I am finding in docs is not working.

Here is my code (I wish for the queries and transactions to be part of the block) - the following lines are just stuff I need, but they work fine:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

alter system flush buffer_cache;
alter system flush shared_pool;

CREATE OR REPLACE function timestamp_diff(a timestamp, b timestamp) return number is 
begin
  return extract (day    from (a-b))*24*60*60 +
         extract (hour   from (a-b))*60*60+
         extract (minute from (a-b))*60+
         extract (second from (a-b));
end;
/
```

Here I have created my block. This version is empty but it runs.

```
DECLARE 
    inde_x number(4);
    temp_be timestamp;
    temp_af timestamp;
    temp_diff_a long;
    temp_diff_b long;
    temp_diff_c long;
    temp_diff_d long;
    temp_diff_e long;
    temp_diff_f long;
    temp_diff_g long;
BEGIN 
   FOR inde_x in 1 .. 1 LOOP 
    temp_be := current_timestamp;

    Rollback;
    
    temp_af := current_timestamp;
    temp_diff_a := timestamp_diff(temp_af, temp_be);
    dbms_output.put_line(temp_diff_a);

    
    temp_be := current_timestamp;


    
    temp_af := current_timestamp;
    temp_diff_b := timestamp_diff(temp_af, temp_be);
    dbms_output.put_line(temp_diff_b);

    
    temp_be := current_timestamp;


    
    temp_af := current_timestamp;
    temp_diff_c := timestamp_diff(temp_af, temp_be);
    dbms_output.put_line(temp_diff_c);  

    
    temp_be := current_timestamp;


    
    temp_af := current_timestamp;
    temp_diff_d := timestamp_diff(temp_af, temp_be);
    dbms_output.put_line(temp_diff_d);  

    
    temp_be := current_timestamp;


    
    temp_af := current_timestamp;
    temp_diff_e := timestamp_diff(temp_af, temp_be);
    dbms_output.put_line(temp_diff_e);

    
    temp_be := current_timestamp;


    
    temp_af := current_timestamp;
    temp_diff_f := timestamp_diff(temp_af, temp_be);
    dbms_output.put_line(temp_diff_f);
    
    
    temp_be := current_timestamp;
    
    
    
    temp_af := current_timestamp;
    temp_diff_g := timestamp_diff(temp_af, temp_be);
    dbms_output.put_line(temp_diff_g);
    INSERT INTO time_in_ms (run_id, query_one, query_two, query_three, transaction_one,  transaction_two, transaction_three, transaction_four)
    VALUES (inde_x, temp_diff_a, temp_diff_b, temp_diff_c, temp_diff_d, temp_diff_e, temp_diff_f, temp_diff_g);
  END LOOP; 
END;
```

Here I some sample queries and transactions. The finished version will be much bigger. These queries and transactions all work as they are now. However I want them to be in the block where the time they require will be also measured.

```
--query_one

select villager_id from villagers 
inner join families
on villagers.family_id = families.family_id
inner join houses
on families.house_id = houses.house_id
inner join villages
on houses.village_id = villages.village_id
inner join locations
on villages.location_id = locations.location_id
order by villagers.age;

--query_two

select families.family_id, count(animals.animal_id) from animals
left join villagers
on animals.animal_id = villagers.animal_id
left join families
on villagers.family_id = families.family_id
WHERE families.family_happiness 
between 
(select avg(family_happiness) from families)-0.4
and 
(select avg(family_happiness) from families)+0.4
GROUP by families.family_id
ORDER by families.family_id;

--query_three
--something with dates



--transaction_one

update jobs j
set j.wage = j.wage*(10 + dbms_random.value*0.5)
where j.villager_id in (
select v.villager_id from villagers v
inner join families
on v.family_id = families.family_id
inner join houses
on families.house_id = houses.house_id
inner join villages
on houses.village_id = villages.village_id
inner join locations
on villages.location_id = locations.location_id
where j.location_id != villages.location_id);

Rollback;


--transaction_two
--something that changes strings 


--transaction_three


update jobs j
set j.risk_factor = j.risk_factor/2
WHERE j.job_name NOT LIKE '%De%' or j.job_name NOT LIKE '%Po%' or j.job_name NOT LIKE '%En%'
and j.location_id in (
SELECT l.location_id from locations l
left join villages
on l.location_id = villages.location_id
WHERE l.location_name NOT LIKE '%De%' or l.location_name NOT LIKE '%Po%' or l.location_name NOT LIKE '%En%'
AND villages.village_name NOT LIKE '%De%' or villages.village_name NOT LIKE '%Po%' or villages.village_name NOT LIKE '%En%'
AND l.Max_Number_of_Animals > 10
AND l.food_content < (
SELECT avg(ll.food_content) from locations ll
WHERE ll.Max_Number_of_Animals > 10));

Rollback;

--transaction_four


update animals a 
set a.meat_content = CASE 
WHEN a.domesticated = 'true'
THEN a.meat_content*(1.1 + dbms_random.value*0.30)
ELSE a.meat_content*(1.05 + dbms_random.value*0.15)
END
WHERE a.animal_id in (
select an.animal_id from animals an
full join villagers 
on an.animal_id = villagers.animal_id
full join jobs
on villagers.villager_id = jobs.villager_id
left join locations
on jobs.location_id = locations.location_id
WHERE (jobs.ending_on-starting_on > 2)
OR (locations.food_content > 0.3)
OR villagers.age between 15 and 50);

Rollback;
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what your actual question is.

Comment: I will update it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED with cursor example:

```
begin
  for c_record in (
         select families.family_id, count(animals.animal_id) cnt
         from animals 
          ... etc ... ) loop
         --do something with the record
         c_record.family_id
         c_record.cnt
         ..etc..
   end loop;
```

If you want to select values in a PL/SQL block, you need to use SELECT... INTO...  you need to declare variables to insert the results of the SELECT into. Example:

```
declare
 vid number;
begin
select villager_id 
into vid
from villagers 
inner join families.. etc;
```

Comment: Yes, however I am trying to do this with rows, and not single values. Also how do I run update statements within the block?

Comment: then declare a record of the required fields and select into the record.